# XCode 4 osx 10.9 - folding methods crashes

Tags: xcode, crash, crash-reports

After updating to osx 10.9, in any of my projects doing the following crashes Xcode 4.6.3:

- fold a method, if statement, for loop, etc
- click on a different file
- click back on the file with the folded code

When clicking back on the file I notice that all the line numbers are gone but the one at the very top (which is usually some random number and it sort of flashes a bit).  Less than 5 seconds after clicking on this file XCode crashes.

This is repeatable.  When I reopen Xcode and open the project, the problem persists.  Now I am unable to access that file.  I've tried closing Xcode and releasing the memory in RAM.  I've tried removing the reference in the project and adding it back.  Yes the problem persists.

This is massively frustrating and has completely derailed my development.  Has anyone else had this issue?  Anyone know how to solve it?

[Here's the crash report](http://www.mediafire.com/view/na3wonve2oj1878/XCode_Crash_Report.rtf) if it's helpful.

-GW

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using xcode 5 which definitely plays better with Mavericks?

Comment: I just haven't updated yet.  I don't like to update a program when I'm in the middle of using it.  Also I've heard a ton of horror stories with 5.0.1.  Once I finish the push on this project I'm planning on upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, but am still curious as to why this is happening and how I can still fold my code without this problem.

- click on the problem file.
- click anywhere where the code should be (sometimes all the code appears to be gone)
- goto Editor > Code Folding > Unfold All

That cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. I fully share frustration and reasons why not going to rev 5.

Here's my solution :

- exit xcode
- go to your `myProject.xcodeproj` file
- look inside the package for `myProject.xcworkspace` file (right click / Show Content)
- back up `myProject.xcworkspace` outside your xcode hierarchy
- delete `myProject.xcworkspace` file
- restart xcode (a clean `myProject.xcworkspace` will be created).

**NOTE**: Works for me, but I'm *not* using workspaces.  I have not tried, but I suppose that if you want to preserve your workspace settings you'd have to selectively delete the `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` files further down in the package hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file to solve these reoccurring code/comments folding crashes in Xcode 4.6.3 running on OSX 10.9.

This file can be found at projName.xcodeproj(Show Package Contents)->project.xcworkspace(Show Package Contents)->xcuserdata->username.xcuserdatad->UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

Note that you will loose all the saved user state info of your project, which means all your open tabs will disappear, folded code will be unfolded etc. And the crashes may start reoccuring if you fold any code or comment again.